# Setting a variable limit on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox, input

I am attempting to set a variable limit on how many checkboxes can be set, based on a previous selection.

In my code I have an option input, where you select your choice (which is the `templates` and `limitTemplate` variables). Then I have some checkbox inputs. Let's say I chose my the option for 2 cards. Then I want to choose two checkboxes below it and then not be able to choose any additional cards.

For some reason my code is saying I am reaching the limit on my first selection, regardless of the card limit option. As you can see in my `#template-number` (where is says "Choose x templates from below") that I am getting the `limitTemplate` to work, at least at that point.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The part of the code where I am trying to restrict the limit is here:

```
 if ($(templateCount >= limitTemplate)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('.tp-template-check[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
          alert("You reached your limit");
        }
```

ps - it looks like a lot of HTML, but it is basically checkbox inputs.

[Here is a fiddle in case you prefer this method.](https://jsfiddle.net/r1pzuj92/)

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
  $('#tp-frequency').on('change', function() {
    var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected').val();
    $('#template-number').html(templates);

    // Setting limit for TP templates

    $('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
      var limitTemplate = templates;
      if (!this.checked || $('.tp-template-check:checked').length <= limitTemplate) {
        $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(this.checked);
        var templateCount = $('.tp-template-check:checked').length;

        if ($(templateCount > 0)) {
          $('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " Selected");
        }
        if ($(templateCount >= limitTemplate)) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('.tp-template-check[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
          alert("You reached your limit");
        }
        if (templateCount == limitTemplate) {
          $('#templateCountComplete').fadeBoolToggle($('.tp-template-check:checked').length == limitTemplate).addClass('block');
        } else if (templateCount > limitTemplate) {
          $('.tp-template:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
          $('#templateCountComplete').hide();
        }
      } else {
        $('#templateCountComplete').hide();
      }
    }); //End of .tp-template-check func
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="section-subtitle">Choose the limit</h2>
<p class="small-description margin25">* Some choices result in more/less cards.</p>
<select id="tp-frequency" class="option-input">
  <option value='' disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
  <option value='5'>5 cards</option>
  <option value='3'>3 cards</option>
  <option value='2'>2 cards</option>
</select>
<div id="tp-template-section">
  <!-- Template Section -->
  <h2 class="section-subtitle">Choose <span id="template-number"></span> templates from below.</h2>
  <p id="test2"></p>
  <p id="templateCount"></p>
  <div id="templateCountComplete"><img src="images/checkmark.png" alt="Template Selection Complete" id="templateCountImg"></div>
  <div id="tp-template-wrap">
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-winter" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Winter</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-winter.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-winter.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-winter" value="Winter">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-spring" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Spring</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-spring.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-spring.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-spring" value="Spring">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-summer" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Summer</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-summer.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-summer.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-summer" value="Summer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-fall" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Fall</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-fall.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-fall.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-fall" value="Fall">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-newYears" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">New Years</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-newYears.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="New Years" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-newYears.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-newYears" value="New Years">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-independence" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Independence Day</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-independence.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Independence Day" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-independence.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-independence" value="Independence Day">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tp-template">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="tp-thanksgiving" class="package-check-toggle">
          <h4 class="tp-template-title">Thanksgiving</h4>
          <img src="images/tp-thanksgiving.png" class="tp-template-img">
          <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Thanksgiving" data-template-image="<img src='images/tp-thanksgiving.png' class='review-img'>" id="tp-thanksgiving" value="Thanksgiving">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you not create a minimal version of this? There's just too much to wade through for such a simple question

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I have removed a very large portion of everything. Here is a more minimized version. Everything needed is basically within that TP limit block of code. https://jsfiddle.net/r1pzuj92/3/

Comment: Even further ... https://jsfiddle.net/r1pzuj92/4/

Comment: @Paul see my answer at your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42858713/2813224

Answer (score 1):

Some of your if statement conditions seem to be incorrect. You encased the conditions like they were jQuery selectors.

Change this:

```
if ($(templateCount > 0)) {
      ...
}

if ($(templateCount >= limitTemplate)) {
      ...
}
```

To this:

```
if (templateCount > 0) {
      ...
}

if (templateCount >= limitTemplate) {
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped! One thing I do not get is if I hit the limit, say 3 for instance. If I uncheck a selected input and click on a different one, it won't allow me to select it.

Comment: I don't think your function accounts for that right now. You will need to add to your "on change" function to make the checkboxes enabled if there is fewer than the limit.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me an idea of how to do that?